# Uib-tab containing UI-GRID

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angular-ui-grid, angular-promise, angular-ui-tabset

I have a `uib-tabset` with four tabs:

```
<uib-tabset active="activeForm">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="One"><ng-include src="'one.html'"></ng-include></uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="1" heading="Two"><ng-include src="'two.html'"></ng-include></uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="2" heading="Three"><ng-include src="'three.html'"></ng-include></uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="3" heading="Four"><ng-include src="'four.html'"></ng-include></uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

it has this controller:

```
$scope.tabs = [
  { title: 'One', route: 'one' },
  { title: 'Two', route: 'two' },
  { title: 'Three', route: 'three' },
  { title: 'Four', route: 'four' }
];

$scope.go = function(route) {
  $state.go(route);
};
```

Each tab has the same structure. They all contain a UI-GRID, and differ only in the data they contain:

```
$scope.dataList = [];
$scope.selectedFile = null;

$scope.gridOpts = {
enableFiltering: true,
enableRowSelection: true,
enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
multiSelect: false,
modifierKeysToMultiSelect: false,
noUnselect: false,
columnDefs: [..my fields..],
onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
  //set gridApi on scope
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
    $scope.selectedFile = row.entity;
    // Switcher selezione/deselezione
    if ($scope.atLeastOneIsSelected === false){
      $scope.atLeastOneIsSelected = true;
    } else {
      $scope.atLeastOneIsSelected = false;
    }
  });

  gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChangedBatch($scope,function(rows){
    $scope.atLeastOneIsSelected = false;
  });

  $scope.getFirstData();
  }
};

$scope.addGridData = function(datalist) {
  $scope.dataList = $scope.dataList.concat(datalist);
  $scope.gridOpts.data = $scope.dataList;
};

$scope.getMoreDataAsync = function(firstData) {
  if ($scope.cancelPromise) {
    $scope.cancelPromise.resolve();
  }
  $scope.cancelPromise = $q.defer();
  TypeOneFileSrv.fileList.get(
    {
      userId: $scope.$stateParams.userId
    }, function(data) {
      if (data) {
        $scope.addGridData(data);
        blockUI.stop();
      }
    }, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        toaster.pop('error', 'Error', error);
      }
    }
  );
};

$scope.getFirstData = function() {
  blockUI.start('Loading 'ONE' tab...');
  $scope.selectedFile = null;
  $scope.dataList.length = 0;
  $scope.getMoreDataAsync(true);
};
```

At least, here is the Service which calls the server. As for the Controller, even the Services of the four tab are the same and differ only in the url:

```
angular.module('app').factory('TypeOneFileSrv', ['$resource', function($resource) {
var typeOne = {
  fileList: $resource('url_for_the_first_tab/:userId/?', {
    userId: '@userId'
  }, {
    get: {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: true
    }
  })
};
return typeOne;
}]);
```

My **problem** is that, even if I added the `blockUI` in each tab, when I open the page containing the `uib-tabset` it seems sometimes it does not load all the data. Because for example I see the first two tabs that have the table populated, but the other two are not populated. Or the first two and the last, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try as shown below.

**app.js**

Inject  `ui.grid.autoResize` module as shown below.

```
var appModule = angular.module("app", [
    'ui.grid.autoResize'
]);
```

**Html**

Use `ui-grid-auto-resize` directive as shown below.

```
<div class="grid" ui-grid="vm.yourGridOptions" ui-grid-auto-resize></div>
```

**css**

Give a `width` for your `grid` as shown below.

```
.grid {
    width: 980px !important;
}
```

Comment: It seems work, but how damn did you do LOL why does it work? I can't understand, I thought it was an async problem

Comment: My pleasure :) This is an issue on `Ui-Grid`.It has number of solutions.But only the above worked for me.Here is the link.https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Grid+is+not+working+with+Tabs